# SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111 Spring Boot , Flutter

Tags: spring-boot, flutter, flutter-test

I am developing an application with Spring Boot for backend and Flutter for the front end.
I need to send the GET and POST requests from the front-end to communicate with the backend and perform the required tasks. I am currently using the **Emulator** on my development laptop and hit the `http://10.0.2.2:8085/abc` URL to perform the task and it is working absolutely fine.
Now my application is complete and I want to run it on my Mobile device. But when I install the apk of the app and perform any task which hits the above URL it gives the error as follows.

> Error :  SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111

Kindly tell how could I make it work on my mobile phone.
I am using Spring boot, MySQL database, and Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you enter the application on the simulator and on the phone from different networks?

Comment: THis is the problem. My Question is how to resolve this.